# Genson serialization for maps with complex keys

Tags: key, complextype, genson

One of the feauture listed on Genson home page is 
"Serialization and Deserialization of maps with complex keys".

While I'm trying to serialize a map with Keys as complex java objects into json string, and then deserialize them back to java Map. The deserialized map keys are always strings. 
Can someone please help me on how to use genson for such complex key map serialization and deserialization?

Here is my code

```
    Genson genson = new GensonBuilder().useClassMetadata(true).useRuntimeType(true).create();
    VO vo = new VO();
    Key key = new Key(18314212, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()),new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    vo.setEndTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    vo.setStartTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    vo.setItemID(18314212);
    vo.setKey(key);
    Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    map.put(key, vo);
    String json  = genson.serialize(map);
    System.out.println(json); //the json map key does not have @Class attribute 
    Map jsonMap =  genson.deserialize(json, Map.class);
    System.out.println(jsonMap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you must know, json does not allow keys that are not strings. 
So Genson will do one of the two things:

- If the key is some basic type (like a primitive) it will then ser it as a string
- If the key is a complex object like in your case it will ser it as:
  [{key:{}, value: {}}]

Now it appears that when the type is unknown it will use toString method on the key, I've opened an [issue here](https://github.com/owlike/genson/issues/63).

So in your case the fix would be to just type the map like this:

```
genson.serialize(m, new GenericType<Map<Key, Value>>(){});
genson.deserialize(json, new GenericType<Map<Key, Value>>(){});
```

Note however that you **also need to disable runtimeType** in GensonBuilder. Because when you enable it, it will just ignore the defined type during serialization.

Comment: Thanks Eugen for your help. do you know of any workaround using custom converters? I can not disable runtime type and do not know what type of objects the map will hold.

Comment: @user2246796 lets continue this on Genson mailing list, I'll post back the final solution here once we find something that works.